# How can I get Android Studio to recognize my library module's jar files?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project that builds and runs just fine, but in the Android Studio editors all my code the depends on jar files is displayed as if it has a compiler error. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

The structure of my project is

```
Project
- AndroidApp
- AndroidLibrary
  - build
  - libs
     - acra-4.5.0.jar
     - activation.jar
     - (More jar files)
  - src
     - (library source code)
```

And here's the contents of the library's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-14.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/robotium-solo-5.0.1.jar')
}
```

The only error I see in idea.log is this

```
2014-05-06 11:45:08,102 [2933958]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Creating VFS corruption marker; Trace=
java.lang.Exception
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.createBrokenMarkerFile(FSRecords.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.access$2700(FSRecords.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.invalidateCaches(FSRecords.java:1613)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.InvalidateCachesAction.actionPerformed(InvalidateCachesAction.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:924)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:236)
```

How can I make Android Studio recognize my jar files? Any other troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Is it also not working in Android Studio when you try to build & run?
Can you also try this instead compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])?

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches ("File -> Invalidate caches" and restart) or sync with gradle?

Comment: I can build and run from Android Studio. There are no build errors and the app runs. It's only in the editors where I see a problem. I get the same error when compiling with the fileTree statement.

Comment: Yes I have tried invalidating the Android Studio caches. It hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a new Java Library Module, and putting all my 3rd party jars in there. I didn't add any java code of my own in that module. Then I made my Android Library module dependent on the the module. My new project structure is

```
Project
- AndroidApp
- AndroidLibrary
  - build
  - src
     - (library source code)
- Java Library
  - libs
     - acra-4.5.0.jar
     - activation.jar
     - (More jar files)
```